# How do I downgrade Tampermonkey Beta

Tags: tampermonkey

My rather complex (1000+ lines) userscript broke after latest TM Beta upgrade. I wish to test if the upgrade is the issue.

How do I downgrade to previous version of Beta?

Comment: Not that easy I suppose unless you have a regular (daily) backup set up for your apps and data, in which case you can extract the old extension and *load it as an unpacked extension* manually.

Comment: I see 4.3.5371 was the previous version on my PC: [zip](https://mega.nz/#!AZ4jWLSL!_NLLG6aGl5JBw3Vv-KJek1HsamhEfQiCpU682ZdG06A).

Comment: If that doesn't work, you'll have to try to contact Jan (derjanb) directly -- maybe by forum PM.  Not sure he keeps old beta versions, and I still haven't found old *release* versions anywhere since he stopped using GitHub. (Anywhere official, that is.)